# Angular Material Snackbar Change Color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 7 with Material Snackbar. I want to changes the color of Snackbar to green.

In app.component.ts, I have:

```
this.snackBarRef = this.snackBar.open(result.localized_message, 'X', {
    duration: 4000,
    verticalPosition: 'top',
    panelClass: 'notif-success'
});

this.snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
    this.snackBarRef.dismiss();
});
```

In app.component.scss, I have:

```
.notif-success {
    color: #155724 !important; // green
    background-color: #d4edda !important;
    border-color: #c3e6cb !important;
    .mat-simple-snackbar-action {
        color: #155724 !important;
    }
}
```

But the Snackbar is still shown in its default colors.

[image]

I can see that the notif-success class has been applied to the snackbar

```
<snack-bar-container class="mat-snack-bar-container ng-tns-c18-84 ng-trigger ng-trigger-state notif-success mat-snack-bar-center mat-snack-bar-top ng-star-inserted" role="status" style="transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;">
```

Why is the custom css not working?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should write that `.notif-success` CSS class on your main styles.scss, instead of the app.component.scss.

If you are wondering, it is the one which is on the same directory level as your index.html, package.json, etc.

Answer (score 11):

In Angular 15, the [answer by Egemen Çiftci](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74668723/4743630) is the only one that works for me. I extended it to support different background colors for success and error notifications:

```
this.snackBar.open('Success', 'Close', {
  panelClass: 'app-notification-success',
};

this.snackBar.open('Error', 'Close', {
  panelClass: 'app-notification-error',
};
```

In the global `styles.scss`:

```
.mat-mdc-snack-bar-container {
  --mat-mdc-snack-bar-button-color: #ffffff;
  --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: #ffffff;

  &.app-notification-error {
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #f23a2f;
  }

  &.app-notification-success {
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #43a446;
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use mat.get-color-from-palette for some reason with --mdc-snackbar-container-color. It just didn't evaluate value. But I can set --mdc-snackbar-container-color: none; and then use background-color as earlier we did.

Comment: Create a variable and use that: $snackbar-container-color:mat.get-color-from-palette($md-primary, 300);       --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #{$snackbar-container-color};

Answer (score 9):

MatSnackBar colors can be customized by adding this CSS rule to the styles.css file. Tested for Angular Material 15.

```
.mat-mdc-snack-bar-container {
    --mat-mdc-snack-bar-button-color: red;
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: black;
    --mdc-snackbar-supporting-text-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

"panelClass" styles is not being applied to Snack Bar in v15, It's because in v15 the background color is on a different element.

In .css file

```
.style-error {
    color: white;
    --mdc-snackbar-container-color: #FF005D !important;
}
```

In .ts file

```
openSnackBar(message: string, type:string) {    

    this._snackBar.open(message,'Ok', {
      duration: 2000,     
      panelClass: ["style-error"]
    });
}
```

Above code will work for Angular v15.

Comment: It is shame that I cannot use mat.get-color-from-palette for some reason. It didn't evaluate value from function. it just stays as is. So in browser I found value being mat.get-color-from-palette($somepalette, 300)

Answer (score 4):

::ng-deep is deprecated as stated by @Akber Iqbal. Put the following code in the **global** *css* or *scss*

```
snack-bar-container.mat-snack-bar-container {
  color: #155724 !important;
  background-color: #d4edda !important;
  border-color: #c3e6cb !important;
}

div.mat-simple-snackbar-action {
  color: red !important;
}
```

This styling code worked on @angular/material@11.2.2 with @angular/core@11.2.3 
**Note:** *It doesn't work in the component css or scss*

Comment: this solution works for me, when you debug on the webbrowser you find that the css is ignore for the specified in the default theme, so the solution is to be more specific when setting the css like in this case using the selector snack-bar-container.mat-snack-bar-container

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
panelClass: 'notif-success'
```

Try:

```
extraClasses: ['notif-success']
```

I had the same issue and stumbled across this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-snackbar) that had a working example.

Just realized `extraClasses` is deprecated, the accepted answer is probably better here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
::ng-deep .mat-snack-bar-container{
  color: #155724 !important;
  background-color: #d4edda !important;
  border-color: #c3e6cb !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-simple-snackbar-action {
  color: red;
}
```

complete [working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-example-dzvdzp?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated