# Angular Material MatSnackBar panelClass not working

Tags: angular-material

Since the update to Material 15 I have problems with the `panelClass` Property. It didn't work since update.
My styles.scss like:

```
::ng-deep .success-dialog-snackbar {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: green !important;
}

::ng-deep .error-dialog-snackbar {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: darkred !important;
```

MatSnackBar calling:

```
  success(message: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, '', {
      duration: 5000,
      panelClass: ['success-dialog-snackbar']
    });
  }

  error(message: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, '', {
      duration: 5000,
      panelClass: ['error-dialog-snackbar']
    });
  }
```

The MatSnackBar calling is in a Angular Service which get an call from an Error Interceptor

Has something changed in Material 15?

I have tried to leave `::ng-deep` but also still not working

Comment: I did this [MatSnackBar colors can be customized by adding this CSS rule to the styles.css file. Tested for Angular Material 15.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74668723/11843160)